# How to configure Nginx ProxyPass to respect AWS load balancer health check?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to get Nginx to reverse proxy to an internal load balancer, like this:

```
Public web client (browser pointing to https://solace-web-console.dummy1.dummy2.com) -->

  K8 pod/container running nginx (AWS EKS) -->

    AWS ELB (Internal facing Network Load Balancer) -->

      Active Solace node (Dormant node also exists, but should not get traffic from ELB since health check fails)
```

The load balancer is in an AWS account that I have no control over, so I cannot make any changes to it.
Here's the nginx config:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     solace-web-console.dummy1.dummy2.com;

    resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local;
    set $awsilb "https://dummy3.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:943";

    access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass $awsilb;
    }
}
```

When I point my web browser to https://solace-web-console.dummy1.dummy2.com, I do get the login home page that is being served out by the Solace node.  But when I try to log in, it sporadically hangs and kicks me back out to the login page.

I shelled into the nginx container, and watched the netstat output during another attempt.  I noticed that nginx is establishing connections to both IPs that the ELB resolves to.  One of the IPs is the active Solace node, and the other is the dormant Solace node.  So I think it's DNS resolving "dummy3.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", and perhaps load balancing between the two IPs, which is causing the problem.

As a test, I replaced "dummy3.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" with the IP of the active Solace node, and the problem goes away.  I am able to log in to the Solace console without problem.

I've tried the same setup, but swapping Nginx with Apache and also HAProxy.  But I get the same problem regardless.

Given the above, I suspect the question is how to configure Nginx to respect the health check of the internal load balancer?